# Как увеличивать id на +1 в mysql без AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: python, mysql, telebot

Делаю телеграмм бота на telebot. Пользователь пишет команду `/start` и добавляется в БД с `user_id` телеграмма, и столбцом ID который я создал сам (для нормальной нумерации `1, 2, 3` и тд, для последующей частичной рассылки в будущем). И тут такая проблема, что авто инкремент оставляет цифру в памяти. То есть, если пользователь уже есть в БД, и пишет ещё раз `/start`, в БД он не добавляется, но следующий пользователь которого не было получает ID с пропуском цифры, потому что цифра предыдущего зарегистрированного осталась в памяти. То есть получается `1, 2, 9, 10` и тд.
Собственно, как можно реализовать id+1? Или как то по другому можно?

```
def process_database(message):
    try:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "INSERT INTO people (user_id) VALUES ($s)"
        val = (message.from_user.id, )
        cursor.execute(sql,val)
        db.commit()
    except Exception as e:
            pass
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Введите текст для перевода.')
```

ОБНОВЛЕНО:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код покажите.       .

Comment: Снизу показал,тут изображение вроде не прикрепить

Comment: При супер желание то что вы хотите сделать, вы сделаете. Но это не профессионально + череваты последствия таких действий. и лишния нагрузка на бд. Вам придеться каждый раз делать доп. запрос на проверку а нету ли там часом уже этого айди.

Comment: @Pavel8289 Один SELECT перед вставкой нового клиента - это сущие пустяки для СУБД - сплошь и рядом сценарии гораздо сложнее и ресурсозатратнее - при этом системы от этого ни сколько не тормозят. Да и не думаю, что у Артём Петров там будет hi-load приложение с миллионами пользователей и дополнительный запрос как-то существенно повлияет на производительность системы. А в целом, вы, конечно, правы.

Comment: Вас попросили код показать, а не картинку. Код всегда текст. Если вы не знаете как его копировать, то задайте новый вопрос: "Какой комбинацией клавиш копировать и вставлять текст в редакторе XY?". Спасибо!

Comment: превышение допустимой длины на 896 символов

Comment: Ну не в комментарий же, в [ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1126679/edit).

Comment: Я решил делать проверку на существование такого users_id,только не понимаю как это сделать.То есть айди юзера это - message.from_user.id. Как мне проверить существует ли такой id,и если нет то выполнить запрос на добавление?

Comment: Поле, которое вам нужно, не содержит никакой новой информации, а поэтому не нужно его хранить в базе. Добавьте поле даты создания записи(для стабильной сортировки) и потом сможете вычислять номер этой записи в текущей сортировке или выбирать нужный диапазон записей.. См. LIMIT

Answer (score 0):

Лучше не пользоваться такой ручной темой id+1. Могут быть дубликаты. Автоинкремент сделайте как и положено. А рядом ваше поле и там "инкрементируйте" уже как хотите. Например при вставке сделайте select Count  и +1. Либо вариант. Рядом служебная таблица с автоинкрементом, куда вставляете что либо. Вам надо только для получения автоинкремент поля.Когда точно знаете что запись будет вставлена. Считываете с нее ID  и вставляете в свою.  Я так делал когда мне нужно было каждый год обнулять нумерацию документов. Но потеря номера была недопустима. Я обнулял служебную таблицу truncate table. Но в основной всеравно был автоинкремент. Он шел дальше.
по типу получится:

```
AI    Ваша нумерация 
30    50
31    51
32    1   (с нового года)
33    2
34    3
...
```

Comment: ID с автоинкрементом,и нужно для рассылки.У меня там только 2 стобца,id которое должно нумероваться для будующей рассылки,и users_id(айди самого пользователя телеграмма)Я не совсем понял как вы имели ввиду,но нужно сделать так что бы было 1 id поле без "косяков" по которому я сделаю админку и можно будет делать рассылку выборочно(например 0-1000)

Comment: Выбрать первую тысячу записей в текущей сортировке можно и без поля со значениями 0-1000.

Answer (score 0):

> с пропуском цифры

Откажитесь вообще от инкремента - генерируйте случайное число или UUID каждый раз. Или вообще используйте `user_id` телеграмма как собственный ID. Такой вариант будет оптимальнее всего без ущерба производительности.

> И тут такая проблема,что авто инкремент,оставляет цыфру в памяти

Причина ошибки, вероятно, из-за того, что не откатилась транзакция, в которой sequence с ID увеличился.

Я думаю, вам нужно перед созданием INSERT проверять, что такой клиент уже создан, и если отсутствует, то только тогда делать INSERT.

```
INSERT INTO people (users_id)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT %s) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT users_id FROM people WHERE users_id = %s
);
```

Ещё можно использовать синтаксис: `INSERT IGNORE INTO table` или `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

В общем и целом, пропуск номеров не должен быть для вас критичен - это ведь всего-лишь идентификатор записи в базе.

Если вы очень хотите обойтись без AUTO_INCREMENT, то можно было бы предложить сделать свой аналог sequence или например для каждого пользователя самостоятельно генерировать ID таким методом: select max(id) from table или select count(id) from table.
Но эти варианты хуже по производительности)

Comment: Можете подсказать как проверять создан ли такой клиент уже?Я не хочу обойтись без авто инкримента.Просто нужно что бы не было пропусков,так как если какой то пользователь напишет 100 раз старт,или 50 по 5 раз,то будет много пропусков,и рассылка когда по id напишешь по 0-100 разошлётся 10 людям,так как кто то написал много раз.Глупо обьяснил,но думаю вы поняли)Помогите сделать проверку на существует ли уже такой user_id

Comment: Обновил свой ответ выше. Попробуйте что-то из этих вариантов:
`INSERT INTO ... WHERE NOT EXISTS...`, `INSERT IGNORE INTO table...`,  `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: "Или вообще используйте user_id телеграмма как собственный ID"Не понял,что это значит?

Comment: удалите в таблице поле ID, а поле users_id сделайте PRIMARY_KEY

Comment: так user_id это айди самого пользователя в телеграмме.а id это его нумеровка для рассылки

Comment: Ну я думаю проще будет на sql языке как вы и показали делать проверку,надеюсь получится

Comment: вставилI NSERT INTO people (users_id) SELECT * FROM (SELECT %s) AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT users_id FROM people WHERE users_id = %s),ошибка: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement

Comment: Попробуйте в val добавить столько параметров, сколько есть %s в строке выше:

val = (message.from_user.id, message.from_user.id)

Comment: `не откатилась транзакция` - откат транзакции не откатывает последовательности, получение нового значения последовательности атомарно и вне механизма транзакций. Иначе было бы невозможно обеспечить консистентность генератора в параллельно существующих транзакциях.